# How to use function template signature for template (member) functions?

Tags: c++

I want to create a (member) function that creates functor objects.
I want to provide the necessary template parameters as a function signature, e.g.:

```
auto f = create<int(double)>();
```

I know that for objects (like `std::function`) the way to go is:

```
template <class, class>
struct Functor;

template <class Ret, class... Args>
struct Functor<Ret(Args...)>  {
};
```

How can i achieve the same behavior for template (member) functions?
Is it possible to realize in c++11?

Comment: you seem to confuse the type of the function `int(double)` with a list of types with return type and arguments types as in `class Ret, class... Args`. I am not sure which one you actually want.

Comment: or is that the quesiton? How to get from the function type `int(double)` to the parameter pack `int,double` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function templates are rather limited when it comes to specialization, but you can forward to a class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
struct create_impl;

template <typename Ret,typename...Args>
struct create_impl<Ret(Args...)> {
    auto create() { return std::function<Ret(Args...)>(); }
};


template <typename F>
auto create() { return create_impl<F>{}.create(); }

int main() {
    auto f = create<int(double)>();
}
```

I am not sure if this is really waht you are asking for. If it is you might want to add a concept to make sure `F` is actually a function type. I tried to keep it simple here.